# My google map marker doesn't appear in the website

Tags: google-maps

I have tried this code on my own appserv localhost. It works well (both the map and the marker). However, when I uploaded it into remote server, the marker doesn't show up. I have no idea what's wrong since I don't even modify the google example code. Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
ps. phpsqlajax_genxml2.php works well on the server since I've test by calling it and it return the correct marker's xml format.
(Here's my code)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAw5y75j6U0CGDJO5dXVWsNBQJj0SM6Mv3a5iwK2VJb-LCBMoC8RRKLU5qU6F7IDJ5DMhWA8SbiexiZA" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
    iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
    iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
    iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
    iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);

    var iconRed = new GIcon(); 
    iconRed.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
    iconRed.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
    iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
    iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);

    var customIcons = [];
    customIcons["restaurant"] = iconBlue;
    customIcons["bar"] = iconRed;

    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        //map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
       // map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(7.638179, 99.030762), 12);

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        GDownloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>       


                  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 170px; height: 250px"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to change the API key to reflect the remote server's domain name.